# proof that $\sqrt(2)$ is irrational / why is the fraction irreducible

Tags: proof-explanation

The proof that shows the square root of 2 is irrational starts by assuming, for a contradiction, that it is rational. It starts with the assumption that it can be written as p/q where p and q have no factors in common.

Why do we start by assuming p and q have no factors in common? If we went on to find that they have factors in common, we could cancel them later on?

Comment: In an actual fraction, can you really keep cancelling indefinitely?

Comment: @Perfect Pans  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Every natural number can be factored uniquely into a finite product of prime numbers. Hence every fraction of natural numbers will have a simplest form.